# NVivo IRR Test of Content Analysis Data: How do I interpret each row of Kappas?

Tags: reliability, software, qualitative

I am currently working on a research project that involves content analysis of secondary published data (corporate sustainability reports) by U.S. companies. In order to capture the data, I and two student research assistants are coding sections of the sustainability reports. We are using NVivo Version 11 to do the coding. There are 24 total codes (“nodes” in NVivo language). Prior to posting this request to Stack Exchange, I engaged in several email and telephone discussions with the NVivo Help personnel in Australia. However, I was unable to obtain satisfactory resolution of the issues.
My questions and issues pertain to how I can interpret the output of the IRR procedures in Nvivo.

**Procedures**

For the IRR test, we each coded the same three corporate sustainability reports.

Next, I received the two students’ NVivo files of this data and I imported both into my NVivo file. I followed the instructions on the NVivo site to do the import:
http://help-nv11.qsrinternational.com/desktop/procedures/import_items_from_another_nvivo_project.htm

With respect to the data import, I chose the option “Merge into existing item” for duplicate items. This was per the NVivo instructions for doing a coding comparison query.

Next, I ran a coding comparison query following these NVivo instructions:
http://help-nv11.qsrinternational.com/desktop/procedures/run_a_coding_comparison_query.htm

**Issues**

With respect to the Kappa calculation for the IRR test, there are three coders on this project, and I understand that NVivo can only calculate IRR for two coders (or two groups) following Cohen’s Kappa. Therefore, for my initial test I specified Student Coder # 1 as “Group A” and Student Coder # 2 as “Group B”. When I ran the coding query, the results I received were confusing. Rather than obtaining the Kappa and Percentage Agreement for each node, the output showed Kappa and Percentage Agreement for each Report coded under a specific node. Further, the output seemed to include “me” even though I did not include “me” in either Group A or Group B (since NVivo cannot simultaneously calculate Kappa for three coders). For “me”, the Kappas were all “1” and Percentage Agreement was “100”. For the Group A and Group B coders, the Kappas ranged from .49 to .99, most were > .70, and some were 1. Another issue is that in the NVivo IRR output I cannot see which coder has applied a code to a respective coding unit.
In order to try to solve the problem of NVivo including “me” in the IRR output (Kappas all of “1”) even though Groups A and B only included the two student coders, I tried to do another import of student data whereby I imported only one student coder’s data at one time. I then ran another coding query with “me” as Group A and Student Coder # 1 as Group B. The Kappa output showed either .5 or 1 for every node. That too seems odd; i.e., that there were no Kappas other than .5 or 1. Next I created a new file with my data, importing the data from Student # 2, and re-running the IRR test. Again, the Kappas were only .5 or 1.

*Hence, my question is: How do I interpret each row in the attached figure?*

[image]